# How to remove observations with filters like count(x)>2?

Tags: r, count

Suppose the data frame is like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "c"), y = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005"))
```

I want to only keep records:

```
	x	y
	b	003
	c	005
```

To get this result, I did this:

```
df %>% filter (count(x)<2) -> df1
```

and I got this error:

```
Error: no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to `filter` the groups having less than 2 observations, we can group by 'x' and then `filter` the number of rows (`n()`) less than 2.

```
df %>%
   group_by(x) %>% 
   filter(n()<2)
#  x   y
#1 b 003
#2 c 005
```